# Как сравнить значение в ячейке со средним значением по столбцу

Tags: excel, макрос

Прошу помощи в решении [задачи](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR4gy.jpg). Нужно в выделенном диапазоне посчитать среднее значение расхода топлива и сравнить его построчно с еждневным расходом.

Вот что получилось, дальше осталось только сравнить со средним значением, но я не могу понять как это сделать, и правильно ли я делаю

```
Sub РасходТоплива()
Dim i As Range

Set i = Selection

Dim Average As Single

 Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select

 Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*100/RC[-2]" ' находим расход топлива на 100 км

 Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select

 Average = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Columns(3)) 'находим среднее значение расхода топлива на 100 км

End Sub
```

Comment: Напишите что вы уже сделали и что именно не получается. Тут не принято выполнять полностью учебные задания.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub РасходТоплива()
Dim r As Range
Dim dLen As Double, dVol As Double
Dim i As Long
    Set r = Selection  ' выделенный диапазон в переменную '

    For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count ' циклом по диапазону '
        dLen = dLen + r(i, 1) ' общий километраж '
        dVol = dVol + r(i, 2) ' общий расход топлива '
    Next i

    ' если километраж есть, определяем средний расход на 1 км '
    ' задействуем использованную ранее переменную '
    If dLen > 0 Then dVol = dVol / dLen

    For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count ' циклом по диапазону '
        If r(i, 1) > 0 Then ' километраж в строке есть '
            Select Case r(i, 2) / r(i, 1) ' расход топлива в одной записи '
            Case Is < dVol ' расход меньше среднего '
                Cells(r.Row + i - 1, 3) = "ниже"
            Case dVol ' расход равен среднему '
                Cells(r.Row + i - 1, 3) = "равно"
            Case Is > dVol ' расход больше среднего '
                Cells(r.Row + i - 1, 3) = "выше"
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```